# incorrect use of html display property

Tags: html, css

this is part of my html code. The issue is that my timer with timer id timerel and my html form are not being properly displayed. My footer has a display relative and has width and top set. When I change them, part of my timer is displayed. Can anybody help me solve this issue?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#canvas {
  background: #99afa3;
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#c {
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#timerel {
  background: #eeeeee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <!--<img alt="logo" src ="images/logo.png" style="float: left"/>-->
    <a href="profile.php"><i></i>Profile</a>
    <a href="info.php">Info</a>
    <a href="ranking.php">Ranking</a>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<aside style="background-color:#E0F9A1; float:right; width:300px; height:550px">
  <p style="font-size:20px"> Poor Snoopy is sad. Help him to get out of the maze by giving commands. </p>
  <img src="GameImg1.jpg" alt="GameImage" />
</aside>
<section>

  <div id="c" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;margin-bottom: 10px;text-align: center;width: 10%;font-size: large"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="560">
                This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
            </canvas>
  <div id="timerel" style="text-align: center;width: 15%;font-size: large"></div>
  <!--not display text before timer-->

  <form>
    <!--move box and num box not displayed-->
    <input type="text" id="move" />
    <input type="text" id="num" />
    <button onclick="test();"> click me </button>
    <p id="dem"></p>
  </form>

  <footer style="position: relative; top:570px; width:550px;">
    <div class="footer-icons">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"> </i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"> </i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#google"><i class="fa fa-google"> </i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"> </i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px; font-family: calibri"> Contact us on SnoopyMazeGame@gmail.com </p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: which type of output you need and what was the wrong?

Comment: There's nothing in the timerel div and it has no height in your css so it won't show.  Please can you be a bit more precise with the exact nature of what the problem is - it's not too clear what your issue is

Comment: i have been able to correct my timer. But my form is not being displayed or maybe it is hidden behind my canvas. Can you help me spot the issue? Thank you

Comment: which form not display?

Comment: I have a javascript game linked to my html. So I use the html form to enter commands, and the game responds accordingly. the issue here is that I cannot find my form on my page. I don't really know why, but I think it is because of my footer inline style.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama the html form with id move, and id num.

Comment: but in code snipest form have display

Comment: @BhargavChudasama oh yes...but in my code it is hidden behind the canvas. it is found on the complete left top of my canvas.

Comment: so add your code in `fiddle`